# Powerbuilder: does a change in the computed field trigger itemchanged event

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a computed field called `c_total_qty` in a datawindow which computes multiplication of two fields, one field is a database column and the second one is another computed field.

Now when `c_total_qty`'s value changes, it does not trigger corresponding `itemchanged` event. Are computed fields work this way or there are errors in my code? If computed fields work this way, then what is the workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ItemChanged is all about changes made through the UI, so from what I understand of your description of your situation, no, it won't fire for c_total_qty changes.

As for a work around, I guess the question is whether the root of the change is in a UI data entry or a programmatic value change. If this is a UI change of one of the root values, you can still hook in ItemChanged, but look for the root column being changed. If it's a programmatic change, I'd probably create a custom user event and call it from wherever the root value is being programmatically changed. (In fact, I'd probably recommend a custom user event in both cases, calling the custom user event from ItemChanged in the first case, so that you're ready to handle both situations cleanly.)

Good luck,

Terry.